# Python keep pinging host until reachable. First time not reachable print on console

Tags: python, web-scraping, ping

I am using python's `os.system` to ping a website.

```
from os import system
system('ping www.stackoverflow.com')
```

This gives the below result:

```
64 bytes from 151.101.1.69: icmp_seq=0 ttl=117 time=102.540 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.1.69: icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=101.990 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.1.69: icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=101.690 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.1.69: icmp_seq=3 ttl=117 time=106.207 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.1.69: icmp_seq=4 ttl=117 time=118.015 ms
...
```

I would like, however, to stop the bing once the website is reached and continue pinging if not reached.

```
system('ping -c 1 www.stackoverflow.com')
```

This will only ping once which is not what I want. How can I achieve what I want?

I would also like to print on the console a message the first time the website was unreachable. How is this achieved?

Comment: Using `ping -c 1 ...`, you will receive an exit status indicating whether or not the ping was successful. See the [os.system documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) for details on the return value of `os.system`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) module since you have more control.

An example implementation of a function that will only return if the site is up while it will keep on pinging if the site is down:

```
import subprocess
import time

def ping_until_up(site="www.stackoverflow.com"):
    while True:
        status = subprocess.run(["ping", "-c", "3", site], capture_output=True)
        if status.returncode == 0:
            return
        print("Site is down...")
        time.sleep(30)


# -- Test --
import sys
ping_until_up(sys.argv[1])
```

This gives you:

```
$ python3 ./test.py www.google.com
$ python3 ./test.py asd.asd.asd
Site is down...
Site is down...
Site is down...
...
```

Few things to note:

- I do 3 pings since 1 might lead to false negatives
- You should probably handle different types of errors. In the above example is actually a DNS error. You can do this with the captured output
- This function sleeps 30 secs between attempts and prints in *every* failed round but you can easily change that behaviour to fit your case